# Eclipse JavaFX resource folder isn't showing folder/file but instead coming up as folder.file

Tags: eclipse, javafx, package-explorer

I had a hard time searching for this problem because I can't figure out what search terms to use.  I'm using Eclipse for JavaFX and I'm having an issue in this one project where my folders don't look right in package explorer.  It's been giving me issues in my code saying it can't find folder/file1 because instead of having a folder that expands to show multiple files, instead I have four folders:  folder.file1, folder.file2, folder.file3, etc.

I'm sure that's not very clear (which is why I'm having trouble searching it.  So here's a few pictures.

What another project (in the same workspace!) looks like:

[image: resources folder expands to show files]

^^This is what I want (with subfolders under resources).

What I'm getting instead is:

[image: resources folder acting funky and creating multiple]

And here is my folder structure to prove I'm not creating folders named with dots in the middle:

[image]

Is there some setting or something I can use to fix this? I had this issue early on with packages under the src folder but I was able to fix that through the build path.  I cant figure out how to fix it now that it's not the source path.

Sorry if I'm asking a duplicate question, I just had a really hard time coming up with search terms for my problem.

Comment: Did you somehow make the whole project folder a source folder?

Comment: I think that's exactly what I did, lol.  I had two things as source folder, one was the right folder, and the other appeared to be the entire project, as you said.  If you want to re-post that as an answer, I'll accept it as correct so you get the points.